# Why parallel matrix multiplication takes so long time?

Tags: c++, multithreading, matrix, matrix-multiplication, armadillo

I create test code where I am computing in parallel one complex matrix.

**I am computing on CPU.**

I observed that it takes around 3 seconds to finish all the blocks.

**Can someone explain why it takes so long time ?**

Code

Utils.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <chrono>
#include <armadillo>

namespace utils
{
    class watch : std::chrono::steady_clock {
        time_point start_ = now();
    public: auto elapsed_sec() const {return std::chrono::duration<double>(now() - start_).count();}
    };

    void op_herk(arma::cx_mat && A, arma::cx_mat & C)
    {
        using blas_int = int;
        using T = double;

        const char uplo = 'U';
        const char trans_A = 'N';
        const auto n = blas_int(C.n_cols);
        const auto k = blas_int(A.n_cols);
        const T local_alpha = T(1);
        const T local_beta  = T(0);
        const blas_int lda = n;

        arma::blas::herk<T>( &uplo, &trans_A, &n, &k, &local_alpha, A.mem, &lda, &local_beta, C.memptr(), &n);
        arma::herk_helper::inplace_conj_copy_upper_tri_to_lower_tri(C);
    }
}
```

ThreadPoll

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/thread_pool.hpp>

class ThreadPool {
public:
    explicit ThreadPool(size_t size = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()) : threadPool(size)
    { }

    template<typename F>
    void addTask(F &&f)
    {
        boost::asio::post(threadPool, std::forward<F>(f));
    }
    void wait()
    {
        threadPool.wait();
    }

    ~ThreadPool()
    {
        threadPool.join();
    }
private:
    boost::asio::thread_pool threadPool;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <armadillo>
#include "Utils.h"
#include "ThreadPool.h"

int main() {
    ThreadPool threadPool;
    arma::cx_mat test (256, 30000 , arma::fill::randu);
    arma::vec averageTime(30, arma::fill::zeros);
    std::vector<arma::cx_mat > results(30);
    for(auto &it : results)
        it.set_size(256, 256);

    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
        {
            threadPool.addTask([i = i, &results, &averageTime, test = test.submat(arma::span::all, arma::span(0, 20000)), _ = utils::watch() ]() {
                utils::op_herk(test, results[i]);
                arma::vec r = arma::sort(arma::eig_sym(results[i]), "descent");
                std::cout << _.elapsed_sec() << '\n';
                averageTime[i] = _.elapsed_sec();
            });
        }
        threadPool.wait();
        std::cout << "average " << arma::sum(averageTime)/averageTime.size() <<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Parameters :
gcc 9.4
computer : Intel 6 Cores , 12 threads;
armadillo 10.7.3
openblas 0.3.17**

**CMAKE parameters : set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -msse2 -O3 -mtune=native -flto")**

My results :

```
1.16084
1.16434
1.16571
1.16601
1.17055
1.17118
1.17382
1.17511
1.1767
1.17981
1.18254
1.18537
2.40071
2.40225
2.4025
2.40511
2.40545
2.40565
2.40583
2.40941
2.40972
2.40974
2.41172
2.41291
3.23446
3.23592
3.23734
3.23972
3.24305
3.24484
3.24728
average 2.14871
```

Comment: Take the cout out of the loop for a start - IO is probably way slower than anything else you're doing.

Comment: BLAS calls are generally already parallel. Trying to run them in parallel cause over-subscription which is known to be very inefficient. You need to configure your BLAS to run in sequential, or simply not to run BLAS operation in parallel.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I am using openblas with OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 set. So should be okay. From configuration part